# Restangular POST returns empty parentResource

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I don't know if I understood very well, but what I guess is that when you post with a previous Restangular element that came from server, it should result in a restangular element with the first element as parentResource.

Take a look at this code:

```
// GET: api/vessels
var vessels = Restangular.all('vessels').getList();
this.vessel = vessels[0];

// POST: api/vessels/125/events
this.vessel
  .post('events', event)
  .then(event => { // the server returns the same object but with id filled
    this.vessel.events.push(event);
  }
```

So event should come with 'this.vessel' as parent but it's coming empty:
[image: click here to see the element object on chrome debugger]

The problem is that when I try to `event.remove()` the url of the action is `DELETE api/events/2703` and not `DELETE api/vessels/125/events/2703` as it should be.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. This is what I should had done:

```
// GET: api/vessels
var vessels = Restangular.all('vessels').getList();
this.vessel = vessels[0];

// POST: api/vessels/125/events
this.vessel
  .one('events')
  .post(null, event)
  .then(event => { // the server returns the same object but with id filled
    this.vessel.events.push(event);
  }
```